# adding symbolic link to os x finder sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, symbolic-link

I'd like to add a symbolic link to the OS X finder sidebar, but when I do so the sidebar follows the link and creates a direct link to the target folder.  This is not what I want, the reason I use a symlink is because its target changes, so I'd like the sidebar to keep up.

As it stands when I change the symlink, the sidebar still points to the symlink's original target.

Any way to have a true symlink in OS X Finder's sidebar?